# How to fix issues in Git Interactive Rebase

Tags: git

I am trying to rebase my local branch against the master branch. From my local_branch, I have executed the below command to rebase. I have practiced using the command-line utility (i.e Git Bash) for some time and would like to use the same to fix the current issue.

I can use Visual Studio Code tool to accept current / incoming / both the changes.. But is there a way to perform the same using Git Bash? Also for the below scenario, what would be the preferred way to fix?

```
> git pull --rebase origin master
> git status                                                                                                                                             
interactive rebase in progress; onto 53681c8
Last commands done (2 commands done):
   pick 89bb0987 Updated messenger.xml
   pick 990bn189 Updated messenger.xml
Next commands to do (9 remaining commands):
   pick 6780f98 Updated messenger.xml
   pick 9091m969 Updated updated_numbers.xml
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently rebasing branch 'feature-jd-bulk-messenger' on '53681c8'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
        both modified:   jd-test/admin/messenger.xml
```

Comment: What trick are you using to turn a `pull --rebase` into an _interactive rebase_? Is that supported?

Comment: @eftshift0 It's a badly-worded message, it's just an ordinary conflict during a normal rebase.

Comment: Just do what it says. Resolve the conflict in `jd-test/admin/messenger.xml`, add it, and continue the rebase. What's the question? Is it merely that you don't know how to edit `jd-test/admin/messenger.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an ordinary merge conflict, the changes in your local branch abut or overlap changes in the mainline history, and you need to decide what the result should look like because Git rightly doesn't dare guess.

> is there a way to perform the same using Git Bash?

Yes, decide what `jd-test/admin/messenger.xml` should look like, add that, and `git rebase --continue`, whichever merge tool you like should be able to automate the edit/pick/stage sequencing for you. I use vimdiff which handles this with aplomb, does VS Code's Git integration not understand what's happening here?

For an example,

```
git init `mktemp -d`; cd $_
seq 5 >file; git add .; git commit -m-
git branch -t mine
sed 2s,$,a, -i file; git commit -am2
git checkout mine
sed 3s,$,a, -i file; git commit -am3
git rebase
```

and you'll get a conflict in `file`, where the right result is to take both changed lines as-is but Git can't be sure enough of that to just do it for you. `git status` here will pop a familiar message, I can make sense of it by realizing the rebase is now in fact an interactive one, it's waiting on me, it's interacting with me. I'd do `git mergetool` here.

If you're going to be doing a lot of this, you might want to enable rerere, **re**use of **re**corded **re**solutions: `git config rerere.enabled true; git rerere` before adding the resolution this first time, after that Git will run it for you, running it makes Git will remember new conflicts and resolutions in the index in case they up again in subsequent rebases.